# Implementing incremental compilation for a compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I'm currently trying to implement incremental compilation for my compiler.
I already have a custom file format for storing metadata about compiled functions which is read whenever there's no change to the source code, to avoid having to parse and typecheck the input again.

The idea that I have is using compiled object files as a cache for already compiled code. I do generate one object file for every input file and link them together in the final stage of the compiler.

My language has polymorphic functions which means that inside of the obj file for a certain input file, there exist multiple implementations for the same function using types from other modules.

Now my problem is specifically what happens when you compile a big project (say the compiler) and it creates obj files containing all of these implementations. Now what happens when I compile a simple source file using the same cache? It's going to pull in the obj files with all of these functions defined but the dependencies of these functions (like destructors for instance) don't exist anymore when linking together the newly compiled object files.

This means that I get a linker error because it depends on functions that are no longer defined. I know exactly which functions I need to keep so I'm thinking I could just modify the obj file and strip all the functions that are no longer needed. Is there a way of doing that? It needs to work on both Windows and Linux.

I was thinking about using llvm-objcopy (I depend on llvm for my project as a backend anyway) but when I test it to remove a single symbol I get an error like this:

```
llvm-objcopy.exe -N "main::__main__::([[char]])" .\main.o
llvm-objcopy.exe: error: '.\main.o': '.\main.o': not stripping symbol 'main::__main__::([[char]])' because it is named in a relocation
```

My other alternative would be using multiple caches for every main file compiled, if there is no way of doing this, but I kinda dislike that approach.

However, this would essentially create the same problem because right now I can only add functions. For this I use `clang.exe -nostdlib -Wl,-r,-z,muldefs -o ...` to overwrite the functions inside the obj file. But if there's a function removed it's going to stay inside the obj file.

Comment: What you have is a classic garbage collection problem: When you remove a reference to an object, does the object remain alive? Circular reference chains make this much more exciting.

Comment: I do have a set of root functions that I can use to figure out if a function is reachable or not, but that's like the second step of the equation. First I need to find out how to even remove functions from an object file.

Comment: An object file is a Module and Module lets you [retrieve its functions](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a97db845caa6bba2a5ff3ffb8a2b8c23f).